# Threshold for Mahalanobis distance

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I have training samples that I project onto the eigenspace via pca. What is a reasonable threshold for the mahalanobis distance (to the mean) to reject invalid input data ?

The paper [here](http://www.tamaraberg.com/teaching/Fall_13/papers/asm.pdf) states that a distance of 3 standard deviations would be reasonable. However, the example stated [here](http://www.jennessent.com/arcview/mahalanobis_description.htm) has training data up to 10 standard deviations. What threshold should I set for my application of face recognition ? I have found that the distance of my training samples to the mean can go up to 8-9 standard deviations.

Is there a rule of thumb for setting a threshold for the mahalanobis distance ? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to CV. That two different papers use different thresholds tells you something, namely, that there is no "rule of thumb" and the decision is up to the analyst.

Comment: Awesome thanks ! I had the impression that most of the samples would lie within 3 standard deviations. I guess im wrong and that it depends on the quality of the training data.

Comment: +/-3 std.dev - under the *assumption of Normal* Distribution. N.B. your *assumptions* given to your analysis plays important role in its results. If Normally distributed data, then the *size* of sample also is important - it should be enough to prove Dependency according "*the law of huge numbers*" .

Comment: Besides you can deal with *heavy-tailed* distributions - for detecting outliers [also care about the estimator](https://medium.com/@evertongomede/outliers-and-heavy-tail-distributions-7c68be4f59fa) -- thus, it all depends on your *Assumptions* !
- also NB data to be *iid* - really independent - or [whiten data first](https://christianschluter.github.io/files/published_papers/2008_JEMPFIN_Schluter.pdf)

Comment: can use [DBSCAN](https://detectoutliers.com/2023/03/23/robust-anomaly-detection-with-dbscan-clustering/) - the only parameter you need assume is `eps` - can choose it with [elbow-chart](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/10/outliers-detection-using-iqr-z-score-lof-and-dbscan/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to detect the outliers, we should specify the threshold; we do so by multiplying the mean of the Mahalanobis Distance Results by the extremeness degree k in which k = 2.0 * std for extreme values and 3.0 * std for the very extreme values and that's according to the 68–95–99.7 rule

Comment: That rule is a rather poor approximation to the distribution of Mahalanobis distances (which will have strong positive skew in lower dimensions)--and is far too generous for flagging outliers.

Comment: Thank you, but this is Markov distance I guess for where most data fits in. I don't think this is practical at all and this is very week indeed.